# How to wait for a suspend function to call a non-suspend function in one after another

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following method in my viewModel which calls a suspend usecase.

```
fun clearFirebaseCache() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        clearFirebaseCacheUseCase.execute()
    }
}
```

And in my MainActivity it is called like this:

```
mMainViewModel.changeLanguageConsumableLiveData
    .observeAndConsume(this) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            mMainViewModel.clearFirebaseCache()
            ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this@MainActivity)
        }
    }
```

As the clearFirebaseCache() has to complete first before calling `ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth` I have added a Deferred so that I can wait for it to finish first.

However, I don't like having this `Deferred<Unit>` and would prefer a launch as it just clears the cache and returns nothing.

I think it should be in a `launch` as its not returning anything just a one time call. But as I have to run these in sequence I don't know any other way.

Another thing, having this Deferred makes it more messy as if I want to use this anywhere else I always have to call await, even if I don't have any calls to make in sequence.

This is the final solution

```
Take in a lamba that will be called after cleared cache

fun clearFirebaseCache() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        clearFirebaseCacheUseCase.execute()
    }
}
```

And using it like this, not sure if this is a good pattern or not.

```
mMainViewModel.changeLanguageConsumableLiveData
    .observeAndConsume(this) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            mMainViewModel.clearFirebaseCache(waitUntilComplete = {
                ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this@MainActivity)
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for a suspend function to finish is a default behavior when calling it, we don't need any deferreds, `launch()`, etc.:

```kotlin
suspend fun clearFirebaseCache(): Unit {
    clearFirebaseCacheUseCase.execute()
}
```

Then:

```kotlin
mMainViewModel.clearFirebaseCache()
ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this@MainActivity)
```

As simple as that.

Your approach with `Deferred` or a callback should work as well, but this is the traditional solution and coroutines were invented specifically to replace such patterns with a better alternative. As we can see in the example above, the code greatly simplifies by using a suspend function and calling it directly.

Comment: I used your solution like this `lifecycleScope.launch {
                    mMainViewModel.clearFirebaseCache()
                    ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this@MainActivity)
                }`

Comment: Keep in mind that `clearFirebaseCacheUseCase` will now be executed in the `lifecycleScope` instead of the `viewModelScope`. Therefore, make sure that `clearFirebaseCacheUseCase` also performs as desired when that scope is cancelled, which may happen at any time (on configuration changes, f.e.). Also worth having a look: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices

Comment: @ant2009 Yes, this is what I meant. We still need to launch it using some scope if e.g. we need to execute it from an event handler. But after we get into coroutines world, we can call suspend functions directly and that means waiting for them.

Comment: @Leviathan Yes, I wasn't sure if I should go into such details, because the main question here was how to wait for a suspend function. In this specific case it is important to consider who is the "owner" of the background process and if no one waits for it anymore, then should it continue or be cancelled.

Comment: @Leviathan and broot I am just wondering as I have 2 scopes here. lifecycleScope and viewModelScope. The reason I am using the lifecycleScope so I can call the suspend funtion in the viewModel which uses the viewModelScope. So by default the lifecycleScope will be used to launch the coroutine or will it be the viewModelScope. Is there anyway I can know which scope will be used. I would think it would be the viewModelScope as that is the final one that launches the usecase

Comment: In your original version the viewModelScope was used to execute the usecase. Until you edited your question to remove the Deferred, the lifecycleScope was necessary to unwrap that Deferred. After your edit it just launches clearFirebaseCacheand triggerRebirth asynchronously in the backgroud so it doesn't block the main thread. In @broot's solution the viewModelScope isn't involved at all, everything is executed in the lifecycleScope. It's pretty easy: It's always the scope used that actually launches the coroutine with `launch` (or `async`).